# how to count all the records in A table where B table has more than 2 records

Tags: mysql

Hi I'm trying to count all the users who made more than 2 order.

What I made so far is

```
SELECT Count(*), 
   (SELECT Count(*) AS cnt 
    FROM   order ord 
    WHERE  usr.id = ord.user_id 
    HAVING cnt > 1) 
FROM   USER usr;
```

but I still got total users

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write like this :

```
Select count(*)
from (
Select UserId, Count(UserId) from Order group by UserId having Count(UserId)>2
) Temp
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get user wise order count

```
SELECT usr.id, Count(ord.id)
FROM USER usr
INNER JOIN order ord ON usr.id = ord.user_id 
GROUP BY usr.id
Having Count(ord.id)>2
```

And if you want to count the no of users made more than 2 orders

```
SELECT count(distinct usr.id)
FROM USER usr
INNER JOIN order ord ON usr.id = ord.user_id 
GROUP BY usr.id
Having Count(ord.id)>2
```

Comment: I wanted to count users who made an order more than two so I need numbers of users. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just try to fix your query as i found that you did mistake on projection thats why i used sub-query

```
SELECT * from 
   (    
    SELECT usr.id, Count(*) AS cnt 
    FROM   order ord 
    inner join USER usr
    on usr.id = ord.user_id
    group by usr.id   
    HAVING cnt >2
) as T
```

Comment: Why the nested query?

Comment: no need that i just try to make understandable sub-query to the   questioner ,because he did a mistake when in times of project of his data

Comment: I didn't downvote, but maybe because you just posted code without any explanation of what he did wrong and how you fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM   USER usr
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM order
             WHERE user_id = usr.id
             GROUP BY user_id
             HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets break your query in 2 parts:

1. **All users who made more than 2 orders:**

   ```
   SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS count FROM orders  
   GROUP BY user_id  
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 2;
   ```
2. **Count all users from above result:**

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM (
       SELECT user_id FROM orders  
       GROUP BY user_id  
       HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
   ) required_users;
   ```